# How to disable next key (keycode 117) which is constantly being triggered?

Tags: keyboard, xev

In the past few days whenever I type rapidly a `~` symbol continuously pops up in the terminal window. To resolve the issue I tried running

```
xev -event keyboard
```

This told me that the problem is the `NEXT KEY with key code 117`, so I disabled it using this command:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 117='
```

Now the symbol `~` is not coming but still, its action which scrolls down the current page is still active.

Comment: @pam-lx Would you share output of `xev` and `evtest` for both keys? You may upload output to https://paste.ubuntu.com and share link here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keycode 117 is pagedown key. Check if it's pressed. or try

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 117=NoSymbol"
```

Comment: This doesn't stop page-down from working in chrome and many other applications, so I finally had to physically remove the key from the keyboard.